# How to modify blockquote line from bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, typography, blockquote

I want to if it is possible to modify the `blockquote-footer` line from bootstrap 5? just change its color and width?

Here is the code from bootstrap 5:

```
 <figure>
                      <blockquote className="blockquote">
                        <h1 className="text-start">10 of Wands</h1>
                      </blockquote>
                      <figcaption className="blockquote-footer">
                        Published Date: Oct. 10. 2021
                      </figcaption>
                    </figure>
```

Sample output:

[image]

How to change the color and size of the **`--`**

Tried this but it's now working:

```
.blockquote-footer {
      border-left: 5px solid #AB8D60;
      width: 161px;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Bootstrap's just a pile of CSS. Of course you can modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
<!--
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->



<figure>
<blockquote className="blockquote">
  <h1 className="text-start">10 of Wands</h1>
</blockquote>
<figcaption className="blockquote-footer">
  <span style="Font-size:20px; color:red;" >--</span>Published Date: Oct. 10.   2021
  </figcaption>
 </figure>
```